# Python Script - Skip file with error and continue analyzing other files

Tags: python

I use the below code to extract data between 2 keywords from multiple txt files and store all data in an output text file. If a txt file has any issues, the code stops executing at that particular file and writes the result as "Error in : ". How do I modify this code so that, the code skips the file with error and continue analyzing other files in the directory

```
import os
BASE_DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()
oFullFileName =  BASE_DIRECTORY + "\\" +  "1_Version_Info_Extract.txt"

file_list = []
output = {}
import csv

outputfile = None
lineCnt = 0
def StartWrite():
    oFile = open(oFullFileName, 'a')
    return oFile
    
def WriteIntoFile(f,line):
    outputfile.write(f + "^" + line)
   
def StopWrite():
    outputfile.close()
    
## get list of .las files from current dir
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
    for f in filenames:
        if str(f).endswith(".txt") or str(f).endswith(".TXT"):
            e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
            file_list.append(e)

## create outfile
outputfile = StartWrite()

## read file
try:

    for f in file_list:
        txtfile = open(f, 'r')
        lineCnt = 0

        ## read file data 
        for line in txtfile:
            if (line[0:2] == "~V") or (lineCnt > 0):
                ## write out req data into outfile 
                WriteIntoFile(f,line)

                ## Close reading current file
                if (line[0:1] == "~" and (lineCnt > 0)):
                    break
                lineCnt = lineCnt + 1
except :
    WriteIntoFile(f, 'Error in : ' + f)
## stop writing in outfile 
StopWrite()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with those attempts?

Answer (score 0):

So close!  You just have your try/except in the wrong place.  What you want is:

```
for f in file_list:
    try:
       txtfile = open(f, 'r')
       # ... snip ...

    except:
        WriteIntoFile(f, 'Error in f')

StopWrite()
```